# Very Simple 301 Redirects First line only working in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Have searched high and low for an answer - 301 redirects seem a common issue on here but after much reading I'm stumped!

I have a simple htaccess file with three 301 redirects in:

```
redirect 301 example1.htm http://www.example.co.uk/newexample1.htm 
redirect 301 example2.htm http://www.example.co.uk/newexample2.htm
redirect 301 example3.htm http://www.example.co.uk/newexample3.htm
```

However, only the first 301 redirect is working. Subsequent redirects aren't being followed.

The site doesn't have a CMS - is all just pure css/html.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Try these rules with `RedirectMatch` to target specific page with regex:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/example1\.htm$ http://www.example.co.uk/newexample1.htm 
RedirectMatch 301 ^/example2\.htm$ http://www.example.co.uk/newexample2.htm
RedirectMatch 301 ^/example3\.htm$ http://www.example.co.uk/newexample3.htm
```

Comment: Unfortunately **hasn't worked** is never enough information for someone to help you. If you comment out first rule does 2nd work?

Comment: Apologies. Yeah, I tried removing first line however no change. Tried with and without regex. I've also placed the currently working first 301 at the bottom of the list and it still works.

Comment: ok if you comment out first line does `http://www.example.co.uk/example1.htm` still work?

Comment: Hmm, yes it does. Could it be there's another file somewhere I've not updated, or are there usually only 1 file?

Comment: That's what I suspected. It seems you have rules sitting somewhere else as well. Either directly in Apache config OR may be another .htaccess

Comment: Hey 
That's great, thanks for your help! Will have a deeper look. Glad to know I wasn't just missing something really basic :)

Comment: If it worked out you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.